# Django ArrayField

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

I have problem with ArrayField in django admin. When I trying save object with `None` values, even it wasn't changed, I get error: `Item 5 in the array did not validate: Enter a whole number.` Model looks like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    rank = ArrayField(
        models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    )
```

and field data `4,4,4,4,4,None,4,4`
How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Django form fields will only set null values if it matches one of `EMPTY_VALUES` from validators

```
EMPTY_VALUES = (None, '', [], (), {})
```

`SimpleArrayField` first splits the incoming data resulting in `['4', '4', '4', '4', '4', 'None', '4', '4']`, the string `'None'` does not match the literal `None` so does not get converted to a null value

You need to pass an empty string: `4,4,4,4,4,,4,4` as your field data